# SSRS Line Chart X-Axis group by Month

Tags: reporting-services

everyone. For the life of me I cannot figure out why the X-Axis is pulling 2 dates in each month when I want it to group by each month. In the Values I have:

```
Value Field =RunningValue(Fields!new_actualsalesfromsplit.Value, Sum, "Chart1_SeriesGroup")
Category Field: =Fields!closedate.Value

Category Groups =Month(Fields!closedate.Value)
Group On =Month(Fields!closedate.Value)

Series Group by ["salesperson']
```

The chart should have a line for each sales person, and each month should be a cumulative representation of the sales by that person. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the category field to "`=Month(Fields!closedate.Value)`", or something similar that will net the results you need.  Right now, even though you're grouping by month, you're still telling SSRS to use the atomic data for your X axis, so that's what it's doing.

It may make your task simpler to just add a Calculated Field to your dataset - open the dataset properties window, go to the fields tab, and click "add".  Set that field to your month value, use it for grouping and your X axis.

Comment: I had tried that solution as well and it wasn't coming out right. What I ended up doing was changing the x axis from category to scalar and setting interval type to months and the interval to 1. It solved my problem. Thanks for the help. I'll keep your second solution in mind for future reference.